# bash script - variable expansion of process substitution

Tags: bash, scripting, process, substitution

I'm trying to perform analyses on each column of a multi-column file, and using paste, to rejoin the columns together.  I don't know a priori how many columns there are, so I use "wc -w" and a loop to define an array of commands.  Each command then is a process substitution.  The following script shows what I'm trying, and the output is shown after.  Notably if I echo the array of commands to the terminal, then, with the mouse, cut-n-paste it, it works fine, so it must be the order of variable expansion and process substitution.

In short, I need to have a process substitution *inside* a shell variable.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

-------------- script.sh ----------------

```
#!/bin/bash
f="file.txt";
echo "File contents"
cat $f; 
         # simple solution
echo; echo "First try";
paste <(cat $f) <(tac $f)
         # now define cmd[1] and cmd[2] and merge together with paste
echo; echo "Second try";
cmd[0]="paste";
cmd[1]="cat $f";
cmd[2]="tac $f";
${cmd[0]} <(${cmd[1]}) <(${cmd[1]})
         # but what I really want is something like:
echo; echo "Third try";
cmd[1]="<(cat $f)";
cmd[2]="<(tac $f)";
${cmd[0]} ${cmd[1]} ${cmd[2]}
         # or even better:
echo; echo "Fourth try";
${cmd[*]}
echo; echo "Show the array";
echo ${cmd[*]}
```

------------- output --------------------

```
$ ./scipt.sh 
File contents
A B C
D E F
G H I

First try
A B C   G H I
D E F   D E F
G H I   A B C

Second try
A B C   A B C
D E F   D E F
G H I   G H I

Third try
paste: <(cat: No such file or directory

Fourth try
paste: <(cat: No such file or directory

Show the array
paste <(cat file.txt) <(tac file.txt)
$ paste <(cat file.txt) <(tac file.txt)
A B C   G H I
D E F   D E F
G H I   A B C
$
```

In reply to shellter, here is some sample input.

```
    7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.359106        19.981796       -0.160611       0.027
    7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.363938        19.985069       0.041319        0.035
    7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.363133        19.982094       0.041319        0.068
    7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.360716        19.981796       -0.160611       0.006
    7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.361522        19.981796       0.243249        0.049
    7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.357897        19.986260       0.041319        0.035
```

There might be 100 million lines of data like this.  I need to separate off each column, separate each column into blocks of (say) 1000, then perform an average of each element in the blocks, then merge the averaged columns back together again.  For the example below, if I were averaging over just 2 blocks of 3 elements each (instead of 100K of 1000 each), then the output from column 6 would be:

```
0.0165     # =(0.027+0.006)/2 - 1st row from each size-3 block
0.042      # =(0.035+0.049)/2 - 2nd row
0.0515     # =(0.068+0.035)/2 - 3rd row
```

I already have the program to do this averaging (that's "Some_Complicated_Analysis") and it works fine.  So all I need to for my script to separate off the columns, feed it into Some_Comp_Analysis, then merge the various outputs back into columns again with `paste`.  But, the files are v. large, and I don't know a priori how many columns there are.  If I knew there would be only 2 columns, then `paste <(${cmd[1]}) <(${cmd[2]})` would work fine.

***SOLUTION FOUND***

UPDATE: an answer has been found - it is as shown in the reply update by glenn jackman below.  The `paste` command must be preceded by `eval`.  I don't know exactly why this is necessary, but without them, the variable expansion `${cmd[]}` messes up the process substitution `<(...)`.  The answer above also puts double-quotes around the array expansion `"${cmd[*]}"` however these seem not so important - though without them some other expansions within `cmd[]` might fail.  However, the `eval` is necessary.

Comment: do you need to be using `tac`, or is that just to 'randomize(ish)' your data? . if you really just need to get a bunch of columns side by side, what's wrong with `paste files*` ? Good luck.

Comment: I only use tac in the example.  What I actually have is something like:
`cols=$(head -n 1 $f|wc -w);
for (( i=1 ; i<=cols ; i++ )); do
    cmd[i]="<(cat $f|cut -f$i|Some_Complicated_Analysis)";
done;
paste ${cmd[*]}`

Comment: is there any reason you're not using awk or perl? Take an hour to read http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html and you'll see your problem in a whole new light. If you change your posting to show simplified sample input, expected output, we can probably help you. So you already have code for your 'Some_Complicated_Alanysis'? Good luck.

Comment: I am reasonably good as using awk, better than with bash.  But awk seems inappropriate to me here.  Unfortunately, I'm not so good as to be able to put into words exactly *why* it seems inappropriate.  I have changed my above posting in reply.

Comment: so if your input file has 100Mill rows, your final output will be 100Mill/1000 over N columns? (I'm not going to be around much today, but if you don't get a better solution, I'll try an awk solution as I have the time). Good luck and +1 for good sample data!

Comment: No.  The input has 100M rows, which I split into 100K blocks of 1000 each.  I then average the first element of all blocks, the 2nd element, the 3rd... so the output has only 1000 rows.  What's actually happening is each column corresponds to a physical process (e.g. temperature, pressure etc) as a function of time, in response to some periodic stimulus - in this case the period of the stimulus is 1000, and I want to get the average response as a function of time.  So I'm not averaging *within* each block, but *across* blocks.  I hope I'm explaining myself clearly.  Thanks again.

Comment: yes, after rereading your sample data I finally figured that out. Thanks and back in a while. Good luck.

Comment: See my solution, I'm not sure I'm capturing the way you want to cycle thru the data, but it's definitely a place to start for an awk solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

define each of "cmd1" and "cmd2" as individual arrays

```
$ cmd1=(cat $f)
$ cmd2=(tac $f)
$ paste <("${cmd1[@]}") <("${cmd2[@]}")
A B C   G H I
D E F   D E F
G H I   A B C
```

---

update: You just need to `eval` your constructed process substitutions:

```
cols=$(head -n 1 $f|wc -w)
for (( i=1 ; i<=cols ; i++ )); do
  cmd[i]="<(cat $f|cut -f$i|Some_Complicated_Analysis)"
done
eval paste "${cmd[*]}"   # quotes are important here
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this doesn't avoid the fact that, on the final command, I need to put a specific number of <(...) as arguments to `paste`.  I do not no a priori how many columns there are in the input data.  I need to be able to do `paste ${cmd[@]}` such that the variable expansion inserts the process substitution strings into the command, and then each process substitution is run independently.

Comment: Fingers crossed for 100 mill+ rows! how about preppending `time` to the front of eval? Good luck to all.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have worked though, as usual with bash, I don't understand why.  I would have thought the "" would have substituted $cmd[*] as a single word; but evidently not.  The `eval` seems crucial.
@shelter I'm not so worried about the time - this way each Some_Complicated_Analysis runs in its own process on its own CPU core.  With awk I think it would all run on a single core... right?  But I timed it for you, on an Intel I7 x4 HT, the 6 columns of data took 4 minutes real time.
Thanks to both for your help.  I'll post a conclusive reply later and close the thread.

Comment: @fergalish, the issue is with the shell syntax inside the string. The `<()` and the `|` lose their special meaning inside a string, which is why the `eval` is crucial to evaluate the whole string as a bash command.

Comment: Now I *finally* understand the `eval` section in `man bash`, that is, what it does over and above just merely concatenating and expanding the arguments.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This may be additionally helpful if your script is still not working.  Still follow glenn jackman's answer but in addition you may want to do this inside the script

set +o posix

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection

From link:
**"Process substitution is not a POSIX compliant feature and so it may have to be enabled via: set +o posix"**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  cat -<<EOS
10 7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.359106        19.981796       -0.160611       0.027
10 7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.363938        19.985069       0.041319        0.035
10 7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.363133        19.982094       0.041319        0.068
10 7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.360716        19.981796       -0.160611       0.006
10 7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.361522        19.981796       0.243249        0.049
10 7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.357897        19.986260       0.041319        0.035
EOS
} |
awk '
  BEGIN { binSz=3; binSzLim=binSz ; binSzLim++ }
  NR==1{
    # base error checking on number of cols in first record
    maxCols=NF
    maxColsLim=maxCols ; maxColsLim++
    r=0
  }
  {
    if (NF != maxCols) {
      print "Skipping record, Mismatch in data, expected " maxCols ", found " NF " recs at " NR ":" $0
      next
    }
    r++
    #dbg print "r="r" NR=" NR ":$0=" $0

    # load data into temp arr[] by column
    for (c=1;c<maxColsLim;c++) {
      arr[r,c]+=$c
      #dbg printf ("arr["r","c"]=" arr[r,c] " " )

      avgArr[r,c]++
      #dbg print "avgArr["r","c"]="avgArr[r,c]
    }

    if(r>=binSz) {
      r=0
    }
  }
  END {
    for (r=1;r<binSzLim;r++) {
      #dbg print "r=" r " binSzLim=" binSzLim " " (r<binSzLim) "\t"
      for (c=1;c<maxColsLim;c++) {
        #dbg printf("arr["r","c"]=" arr[r,c] "\tavg=" arr[r,c]/binSz "\t")
        printf(  arr[r,c]/avgArr[r,c] " ")
      }
      printf "\n"
    }
  }
'
```

Produces output

```
10 7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.359911 19.9818 -0.160611 0.0165
10 7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.36273 19.9834 0.142284 0.042
10 7.74336e-08 7.30689e-08 0.360515 19.9842 0.041319 0.0515
```

I added the first column with 10 into the data  to make it easy to debug that sum and avg were working correctly.

An interesting problem, thanks for posting and thanks for your good will in continuing to answer my questions;-)

The `{ cat -<<EOS ... EOS }|` was just to make it easy to run the whole thing in one copy/paste and see that it is working. You can put the awk code if a file with `#!/bin/awk -f` at the top, `chmod 755 myScript.awk` and run it as `myScript.awk BigFile > AvgsFile`.

You should only need to change to `binSz=1000` in the BEGIN block to process your files as you intended.

I'd be interested to know what the timing is on this version.

Comment: I'll get on to this later today.  Cheers.

Comment: #shellter Ok, I've done a brief analysis.  The awk program, surprisingly, uses less CPU time.  However, the original can run on parallel cpu cores and use much less real time.  Here:
`$ time cat file|avg.awk > file.mean
real 15m48.754s; user 16m30.090s; sys 0m13.100s
$ time ../mean.sh file > file.mean
real 3m12.871s; user 20m27.940s; sys 1m3.130s
$`
However, at binSz=1M, estimated time for `awk` was 1½ hours, whereas the original just 4 mins realtime. Next question: how to pipe the same `stdin` to the various process substitutions! Watch this space :-) Thanks again.

Comment: @fergalish : very interesting. Thanks for sharing. Do you have, or can you install GNU-parallel? That might give you the boost you need. Good luck.

Comment: I have since installed GNU parallel and am using it for many other reasons now :-) Thanks for bringing it to my attention.  I have now modified the final script above to do a preprocessing to separate the file into columns, do the averaging and pipe the result to separate pipe-files (mkpipe).  The paste program then runs separately and reads input from all the pipes and merges them.  The only thing to watch for is that all pipes must be written reasonably concurrently, otherwise one will fill and stall the input to the other pipes, and everything stops. Shall I post it?

Comment: I was going to suggest to post it at codereview.stackexchange.com , but don't remember how I got other S.E. related sites to use my openID. Now I'm getting 'No OpenID endpoint found', and have spent 1/2 hr trying to find an answer. I would like to the code. post it, asking for comments and maybe a moderator can tell us how to get logged in for CR. Glad you've made big progress. Good luck.